# OkHttpClient error when making api request to sendgrid

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code where I'm making a PUT request to Sendgrid. Unfortunately, the code is not working. It's using OkHttpClient. Can someone please help?

```
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
        "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
        "{\"list_ids\":[\"X\"]}"
    )
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts")
        .put(body)
        .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer SG.X")
        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

I get the following error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sumizeit.sumizeit, PID: 9738
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1598)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown when application attempts to perform a networking operation in the main thread. Use below code in your onCreate to avoid this error then put your code

```
val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` says, you're trying to perform a network request on the UI thread, which is not allowed.

You must do this in a background thread. Following your code, you could make some small changes:

```
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                // Handle error
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    // Success!
                } else {
                    // Handle response not successful
                }
            }
        })
```

If you are going to update your UI, just be sure to go back to main thread when updating the views, by calling for example

```
runOnUiThread { /* update views safely */ }
```

in the case your code is being executed in a `Activity`.